# YA Sci-fi - Teens with powers trapped in a house

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

I have a book in mind but I don't know the name.
It was a series I think, maybe 3 books. I read them when I was at school 2000 - 2002 but they are possibly from the 80s or 90s. I thought it may have been Point Horror or Point Sifi but have not not had any luck.

There were teens based in a house and possibly did training. The main girl may have been kidnapped.
They had abilities like maybe drawing the future or telekinesis or something. May have been two love interests, the good guy and the bad guy.
I think they eventually escape the house and are then on the run.

- Protagonist: girl
- Love interest: guy called Gabriel
- Front cover: may have been something like eyes faded in the background on top of a graph (one of those that measure stuff like pulses)

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely the *Dark Visions* trilogy (1994-1995), by L. J. Smith. It has a female protagonist who draws the future, multiple teen psychics, and a love interest named Gabriel.

[Wikipedia summary of the first book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Visions_Trilogy) (emphasis mine):

> Kaitlyn Fairchild is a psychic teenager who is believed to be a witch. **Her power is seeing the future. She is able to visualize her premonitions through drawings**, but she often cannot interpret them until it is too late. She is offered a place by Joyce Piper, at **a psychic research center** known as the Zetes Institute, and after seeing a child get hurt, as foreseen by one of her premonitions, she agrees to go to the Institute with four other teenagers who have powers of their own. She quickly befriends three of the other teens, Anna Eva Whiteraven, Lewis Chao and Rob Kessler, and forms feelings for Rob; **the fifth psychic, Gabriel Wolfe is aloof and reluctant to form friendships with anyone except Kaitlyn**...The psychics become suspicious and begin to believe the warnings about the Institute. They investigate and find a secret passageway, which contains plans to turn them into psychic weapons to sell to major corporations, and a file about Project Black Lightning, a previous project in which other psychics were tested upon and 'terminated'...*{at end of book}*...Rob admits to Kaitlyn that he is in love with her, after he realized he couldn't lose her, and **the five psychics escape and decide to flee from the Institute.**

Kaitlyn ends up with Gabriel in the last book.

---

found by googling `psychic gabriel book ya`

Comment: @AMPKBD Please accept this answer as correct by clicking the checkmark under the voting buttons :-)